# CLLocationManager: allowDeferredLocationUpdates - keep getting The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 11.)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, cllocationmanager

After calling allowDeferredLocationUpdates I keep getting 'The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 11.)'

GPS IS available as I still receive normal updates every second. It's just I receive an error every second as well.

I followed all guides I could find, CLLocationManager is initialised properly, all permissions are available. Testing with Console, XCode debugger is not on.

Has anyone seen this and knows what this is about ?

Comment: Please show your code that sets up location manager and requests deferred updates, however if you search here for that error you will see a number of questions/answers where the conclusion seems to:be that deferred location updates no longer work.

Comment: Here is the code that I'm running: https://pastebin.com/nBHb93UX
This is the test app that displays bunch of stuff, but the most important part is probably at lines 39-43 (initialisation), 113-116 (deferred updates scheduling) and 129-135 (handling deferred update errors).

I googled A LOT, and while quite a few people are having issues, for lots of people deferred updates work just fine ! Or at least they don't receive error as I do.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you call the deferredLocationUpdatesAvailable method prior to using the allowDeferredLocationUpdates. Yes, I know, it might seem as unnecessary step if you are on the latest iOS hardware. You might be surprised, though. The deferredLocationUpdatesAvailable returns false on any (6 to X) iPhone. Looks like Apple silently deprecated the deferred location updates as of iOS 10, or may be earlier.

Comment: I tried calling deferredLocationUpdatesAvailable before starUpdateLocation or after or when app goes into background mode - it always returns false.

What's also interesting is that I don't get these errors in emulator, only on real device.

I'm not sure about Apple deprecating it, as there is absolutely nothing about it in documentation.

Comment: Re. I'm not sure about Apple deprecating it, as there is absolutely nothing about it in documentation.  --- That's where the word "silently" comes from :o)

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1620547-allowdeferredlocationupdates

allowDeferredLocationUpdates is deprecated for iOS versions >13.0